# c++ calloc a string array

Tags: c++, string, allocator, calloc

I am having trouble creating an array of strings using calloc. I am unsure if the array is not getting created or not. The program crashes when I try to set the string value:

```
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int counts;
    string* strs;

    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>counts;
    cout<<endl;

    strs=(string*)calloc(counts,sizeof(string));

    for(int i=0;i<counts;i++){
            strs[i] = "Hello World!";
            cout<<i<<") "<<strs[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried using:

```
strs[i].asign("Hello World");
```

but I still get a Windows error that "an error has caused the program to stop working correctly"

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `string` is a C++ class that requires proper initialisation, you can't `calloc` it, you must [`new`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/) it.

```
strs = new string[counts];
```

You probably shouldn't be allocing an array of strings in the first place – why not use a `std::vector<string>`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the constructor of the objects before you can use them. If you insist in using `calloc()` you'll need to use placement new to construct the object, e.g.:

```
#include <new>
// ...
new(strs + i) std::string("Hello World!");
```

Note that you will also need to destroy the object later, e.g.:

```
strs[i].~std::string();
```

The conventional way is *not* to use the C memory management functions at all and rather use `new[]` in the first place:

```
string* strs = new std::string[counts];
// ...
strs[i] = "Hello World!";
// ...
delete[] strs;
```

The C++ memory operators deal with construction/destruction as needed. To get entirely rid of the explicit memory management, you'd actually just use a `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> strs(counts);
```